# If I know my visitor's demographics and features exactly how can I improve my Google AdSense eCPM?

Tags: google-adsense, optimization, cpm

I run a website which got some traffic that I know very detailed information about the vistors. For example `Gender, Interests` and so on.

With that information, can I improve the revenue?

Currently stats:

- UV - more than `40,000 per day`
- 99% of the visitors are on smart phones (Android/iOS)

Comment: To make use of the revenue opportunites from demographic data you have to work around a business plan in the software(website code) to implement that. Please be specific about your website requirments in the question

Comment: Thanks, I don't quite understand what is the "business plan". What I know is the vistors' interest and gender, then what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The information you specified `Gender, Interests` is not a major factor to consider when trying to improve Google Adsense eCPM. What makes Google Adsense so good and popular is the fact they also know your website visitors, and therefor are able to target the ads accordingly.

However, your audience demographics might be useful to figure out other revenue streams, such as premium services, affiliate links and direct ad selling.

Comment: Totally agree, if he has enough solid information about his visitors he can earn a lot more if he uses other revenue streams than adsense

Comment: @Campl3r Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Google maintains an entire help section on [Google Adsense optimization](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2973336).   There is a ton of information on techniques to improve your eCPM.  Too many to fully explain them all in this answer.

The biggest gains in revenue usually come from:

- Placing some ads above the fold near content
- Changing the colors of the ads to match the site
- Using the recommended ad sizes that have the most advertisers
- Making sure you get the most competition for your ad slots by allowing all ad formats and all categories of ads.